# Piece of cement siding came off the house

Tags: siding, cement-board

It is January,  is it too cold to reinstall piece? Also,  noticed a hole on the wall/insulation.  Having issues with rodents.  May be the issue.   How to fix the hole in insulation before reinstall of siding piece?

Comment: Rodents do not like metal, most other stuff they will chew.  Metal can be like steel wool/SOS pads, metal screening, thin steel.  Use metal to cover hole, add insulation, put cement siding back on.